# Cards of same height in tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css. The data in cards is inconsistent. For example some card have short description while other cards have long. Some card contains 1-2 tags while others contains 5-6. I want to make all the cards of same height. Is there any way to do this?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container mx-auto p-6">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-4">
    <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/4 p-4">
      <div class="block bg-white overflow-hidden border-2">
        <div class="p-4">
          <h2 class="mt-2 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl font-Headingg">
            Card Name
          </h2>
          <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap">
            <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
            <span>Link 2</span>
          </div>

          <p class="text-md text-justify">Some Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 flex flex-wrap items-center">
          <p class="px-1 py-2 tracking-wide text-xs mr-2 mb-2">Tag #1</p>
          <p class="px-1 py-2 tracking-wide text-xs mr-2 mb-2">Tag #2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You used flex boxes, so based on your code you need to [algin items](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items) by using just `items-stretch` on flex container. But you also have wrapper on those cards, so also `h-full` well be needed on every card.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container mx-auto p-6">
  <div class="flex items-stretch -mx-4">
    <div class="flex-1 p-4">
      <div class="block bg-white overflow-hidden border-2 h-full">
        <div class="p-4">
          <h2 class="mt-2 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl font-Headingg">
            Card Name
          </h2>
          <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap">
            <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
            <span>Link 2</span>
          </div>

          <p class="text-md text-justify">Some Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 flex flex-wrap items-center">
          <p class="px-1 py-2 tracking-wide text-xs mr-2 mb-2">Tag #1</p>
          <p class="px-1 py-2 tracking-wide text-xs mr-2 mb-2">Tag #2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-1 p-4">
      <div class="block bg-white overflow-hidden border-2 h-full">
        <div class="p-4">
          <h2 class="mt-2 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl font-Headingg">
            Card Name
          </h2>
          <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap">
            <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
            <span>Link 2</span>
          </div>

          <p class="text-md text-justify">Some Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel enim lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 flex flex-wrap items-center">
          <p class="px-1 py-2 tracking-wide text-xs mr-2 mb-2">Tag #1</p>
          <p class="px-1 py-2 tracking-wide text-xs mr-2 mb-2">Tag #2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I removed all responsive widths and wrapping to make it work under preview here.

## Grid

Solution above with flexboxes will work, but for your case (cards) you really want to use [grid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns). It will solve all your problems and make code shorter.

Flex will be helpfully inside card content.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container mx-auto p-6 grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
  <div class="col-span-1 flex flex-col bg-white border-2 p-4">
    <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold text-2xl">
      Card Name
    </h2>
    <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap">
        <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
        <span class="mr-2">Link 2</span>
    </div>
    <p class="text-md text-justify">Some Description</p>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-auto pt-3 text-xs">
      <p class="mr-2 mb-2">Tag #1</p>
      <p class="mr-2 mb-2">Tag #2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-1 flex flex-col bg-white border-2 p-4">
    <h2 class="mb-2 font-bold text-2xl">
      Card Name
    </h2>
    <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap">
        <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
        <span class="mr-2">Link 2</span>
    </div>
    <p class="text-md text-justify">Some Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel enim lectus.</p>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-auto pt-3 text-xs">
      <p class="mr-2 mb-2">Tag #1</p>
      <p class="mr-2 mb-2">Tag #2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now just add responsive `grid-cols-xxx` or `col-span-xxx` based on your needs.

Comment: how did you make the height of the cards same? I can see that your descriptions are different but heights are of the same, and tag is fixed in that position in both of the cards

Answer (score 4):

Best solution, imo, is using `grid` and `auto-rows-fr`.

So, you would have:

```html
<div class="grid auto-rows-fr grid-cols-3 gap-2">
<!-------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this part is important -->

  <div class="rounded bg-slate-100 p-3">This has some content.</div>
  <div class="rounded bg-slate-100 p-3">
    This has more content so that its significantly larger than the other
    items. Yet all items, even the one in the new line will grow to the
    size of the highest container.
  </div>
  <div class="rounded bg-slate-100 p-3">More content.</div>
  <div class="rounded bg-slate-100 p-3">First item in new line.</div>
</div>
```